# Pandas How to extractall() with Nan Values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one column:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsSJH.png)
And i used this command to split the dataframe into a new one with all characters into a column, and the new dataframe looks like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqZuj.png).
The code was:

```
test = useful_data_set.TX_GABARITO_MT.str.extractall('(.)')[0].unstack().rename_axis(None, 1)
```

But the problem is the NaN values was ignored.
What can i do to pass the NaN values to?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post your expected output ([mcve])

Answer (score 1):

First you should find all the NaN values in the original DataFrame column by using `df[pd.isnull(df['TX_GABARITO_MT'])]` and set it to a variable. Then you can contact and sort index:

```
df = your dataframe
df2 = df[pd.isnull(df['TX_GABARITO_MT'])]

test = df.TX_GABARITO_MT.str.extractall('(.)')[0].unstack().rename_axis(None, 1)

pd.concat([test,df2]).sort_index().drop(columns='TX_GABARITO_MT')
```